# Filter wordpress search results depending on which user role is logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying filter search results on my wordpress site, depending of which user role is currently logged in.

I found various filters online which go in the functions.php, but I think i need to modify the function somewhat.

My php skills are basic and this seems to break the site. I'm guessing the syntax is all wrong.

Any pointers on where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
// SEARCH FILTER
function filter_search($query) {
    if (current_user_can('customer')) {
        if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('customers', 'images'));
        };
        return $query;
    } else {
        if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('journalists', 'images', 'videos', 'documents'));
        };
        return $query;
    };   
};
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search');
```

I've created custom user roles, and 'customer' is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem I see with your code is you have an incomplete if statement.

```
($query->is_search) {
```

Should be:

```
if($query->is_search) {
```

That needs to be changed in both locations.

**[UPDATE]** 
Another problem is on both lines like this:

```
return $query; };
```

You don't need the last `};`. That is prematurely closing one of the nested if statements. Just use this:

```
return $query;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) Updated code above. Still breaking site so maybe something else is up.